# Complexity class of approximating perfect match count

Tags: quantum-computing, counting-complexity, randomized-algorithms, dc.parallel-comp, permanent

We know we can approximate perfect matching count of bipartite and approximate volume of convex bodies in randomized polynomial time.

Is there any evidence these approximations could be in Nick's class or in quantum Nick's class?